# Update value in nested object in React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useState:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    options: [{ id: 1, amount: 0 }, { id: 2, amount: 0 }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [{ id: 1, amount: 0 }, { id: 2, amount: 0 }]
  }
]);
```

so I need a function to update the option X from item X.

Like this:

```
const increase = (itemId, optionId) => {
   //setData(...) 
}
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
const increase = (itemId, optionId) => {
    const copy = [...data];

    const dataItem = copy.find((item) => item.id === itemId);
    const option = dataItem.options.find((item) => item.id === optionId);

    option.amount = option.amount + 1;
    setData(copy);
}
```

But it increases by two...

Comment: Why not `setData(copy)` on the last `increase` line?

Comment: Yeah that's the actual  code sorry, I'll update

Comment: Ok nevermind it worked now wtf, before it increased it by two

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const handleClick = (itemId, optionId) => {
    setData((prevArr) => {
      return prevArr.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== itemId) return item;

        const updOptions = item.options.map((option) =>
          option.id === optionId
            ? {
                ...option,
                amount: option.amount + 1
              }
            : option
        );

        return {
          ...item,
          options: updOptions
        };
      });
    });
  };
```

UPD: updated example